# How to add conditional compilation symbols regarding OS platforms in .Net Standard projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have created Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS apps that have a few shared projects.

In the shared project I use the following code:

```
IDataStorage dataStorage = null;

#if __ANDROID__
dataStorage = new DataStorage(Size.SmallData, 10);
#endif

#if __IOS__
dataStorage = new DataStorage(Size.BigData, 20);
#endif

if (dataStorage == null)
 throw new InvalidOperationException("Data storage is not available.");
```

Whenever I run this code, I get an exception (obviously).

So I tried to add those compilation symbols in the *Conditional compilation symbols* part of the project properties, but I realized that if I add both symbols, both section will be compiled.

[image]

Unfortunately, the *Platform list* contains only one item: *Active (Any CPU)*.

So I tried to separate the platforms.

If I try to create a new project platform, I can only choose x86 or x64.

[image]

If I create a custom platform, I can't set it as project platform as it is not supported by any project.

[image]

I can't set it as well, as it does not appear in the list.

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

How can I use conditional symbols in a .Net Standard project regarding to OS platforms?

Comment: If you're creating a netstandard library, I wouldn't expect there to be different versions for different OSes. Instead, if you have OS-specific options I'd suggest detecting which one to use at execution time.

Comment: You are mixing terms here, a "Shared Project" does not equal a "NetStd2 library project". When a Shared "Code" project is referenced by another project, the code is compiled within the context of the project that is referencing it. i.e. for solutions that contain a Xamarin.Android and a Xamarin.iOS library or application project and reference a shared code project, that shared code project could reference the iOS|ANDRIOD conditionals. A NetStd library are x-platform libraries thus they have no platform context during compiling, you could perform runtime if/then|switch to alter the code path.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I had thought it through from that perspective I'd have known that it does not depend on any platform when compiled. I add some runtime check then. @JonSkeet You were the first to react so if you want to promote your comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: It's fine - accepting Jason's answer is probably the right thing to do here, and he's included the bit about the Device class.

Comment: Your comment was very helpful, too :) Also, I don't use Xamarin.Forms so I have to apply different measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .NET Standard library doesn't know at compile time that it is going to be used by Android, iOS, or anything else.  That's why you can't use conditional compilation symbols.

If you are using Xamarin Forms you can use the `Device` class to make runtime decisions based on the platform that is actually running.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - unfortunately, I use Xamarin.Native so I need to find the OS differently.

Comment: you may be able to use the Xamarin Essentials Device plugin with Xamarin Native. Or look at it's source to see what they're doing under the covers to figure it out.